# how to set unknown parameters in get method

Tags: c#, parameters, get, httpwebrequest

how can i set enc from this photo on my app

[image]

my codes :

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my privet url");
req.Method = "get";
req.UserAgent = "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; vivo Y28L Build/KOT49H";
WebResponse res;
res = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
textBox2.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `Accept-Encoding`, you can use `Headers` property of your `req` object just like that:

```
req.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
```

But when you receive response, you need to wrap `res.GetResponseStream()` in `GZipStream` or `DeflateStream` if you want to read response content.